# Increase Primary Key value of existing table by 2 or any other number

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am using SQL Server. I have one table like this with some data where primary key is set to increase by 1 by default

```
CustomerId               CustomerName
-------------------------------------
 1                          John
 2                          David
 3                          Smith
```

Now I would like to make primary key increase by 2 instead of 1 automatically from now onwards without effecting existing data. What would be the safest way to do this ? For example: Now primary key would be 5 7 9 (with increment of 2) in this table.

```
 CustomerId               CustomerName
 --------------------------------------
     1                          John
     2                          David
     3                          Smith
     5                          Angelina
     7                          Johnny
     9                          Tom
```

Comment: "Now I would like to make primary key increase by 2 instead of 1 automatically from now onwards without effecting existing data" - the fact you want to do that leads me to suspect you have an XY problem...

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Also, you need to be aware of and accept gaps in an identity  Take a peek at https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106209/unexpected-gaps-in-identity-column

Comment: @Vim: to put that in context: I've been working with databases for over 25 years and I've never needed to do what you are asking....

Answer (score 0):

Since you **cannot alter an identity column** in SQL Server once it's been created, you'd really only have the option of creating a new table with the new desired structure (including the `INT IDENTITY` column that increments by 2), then copying over the existing data from the existing table, drop the existing table and rename the new table to the table name desired.

Of course, if you have any other tables referencing your existing table with a foreign key constraint, this would make things ever more challenging and involved.